# How do I update and print an int whenever for-loop is ran

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, integer

I made a program where the user is given 10 rounds to make as much money as he/she can using bets. The user gives a bet, then picks heads or tails. The loop works sometimes, but then other times it won't add nor subtract the bet from the total money. Is the for-loop keeping track of all the wins and losses or something?

Here's the code:

```
package wallonsProject;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class WallonProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int totalMoney = 100000;
        
        //Coin faces
        boolean isHeads = false;
        boolean isTails = false;
        
        //CoinToss result
        int coinTossResult;
        
        //number of rounds
        int numOfRounds = 10;

            for(int i = 0; i < numOfRounds; i++)
            {

                //Betting and user Choice
                System.out.println("How much would you like to bet?");
                int userBet = userInput.nextInt();
                
                //User bet must be less than the total money they have or else game exits
                if(userBet > totalMoney)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                
                System.out.println("Press 1 for heads, or 2 for tails");
                int userChoice = userInput.nextInt();
                
                System.out.println("Your starting money is " + totalMoney);

                //coinToss
                double coinToss = Math.random();
                {
                    if(coinToss >= 0.5)
                    {
                        isHeads = true;
                        System.out.println("Toss is heads");
                        coinTossResult = 1;
                        System.out.println("The toss is " + coinTossResult);
                    }
                    if(coinToss < 0.5)
                    {
                        isTails = true;
                        System.out.println("Toss is tails");
                        coinTossResult = 2;
                        System.out.println("The toss is " + coinTossResult);
                    }
                    
                    System.out.println("You chose " + userChoice);
                    
                    //All different outcomes of WINNING results
                    if(isHeads == true && userChoice == 1)//if your choice is heads and cointossresult is heads
                    {
                        System.out.println("You win");
                        totalMoney = totalMoney + userBet;
                    }
                    if(isTails == true && userChoice == 2)//if your choice is tails and cointossresult is tails
                    {
                        System.out.println("You win");
                        totalMoney = totalMoney + userBet;
                    }
                    
                    //All different outcomes of LOSING results
                    if(isHeads == true && userChoice == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You lose");
                        totalMoney = totalMoney + userBet;
                    }
                    if(isTails == true && userChoice == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You lose");
                        totalMoney = totalMoney - userBet;
                    }
                    
                    
                    System.out.println("You bet " + userBet);
                    System.out.println("Your total money is " + totalMoney);
            }

        }

    }        

}
```

Comment: This isn't your question, but you'll want to reset `isHeads` and `isTails` after each iteration, otherwise they'll eventually both be stuck at `true`. Why not just use one variable that's `true` for heads and `false` for tails, so you avoid this risk? EDIT: actually, that's the precise problem. Let me write this up.

Comment: Hi, was your question answered? If so, could you please accept and upvote the answer? If not, what can be clarified?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of your for-loop, you define two variables:

```
boolean isHeads = false;
boolean isTails = false;
```

Inside the loop, if you ever flip heads, you make `isHeads` true, and if you ever flip tails, you make `isTails` true. Unfortunately, you never reset these, so they become 'stuck' in the `true` position.

Because they're stuck, you later hit two conditions in your list of conditions, not just one. You add then subtract the bet, so the total doesn't wind up changing.

---

And one small thing:

```
                if(isHeads == true && userChoice == 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("You lose");
                    totalMoney = totalMoney + userBet;
                }
```

Right there, you probably wanted to subtract the bet, like you do further down.

---

It's not the cleanest way to fix your code, but it's the least typing: as the last instruction in the loop, you should clear out `isHeads` and `isTails` by setting both to be `false`. A cleaner way will require some refactoring: just use one variable that's true for heads and false for tails, so you avoid this risk. Then every time you flip, you're resetting it anyway.